# Assign a number to each unique value in a list of lists

Tags: arrays

I have a list of lists of strings which I want to convert into a unique number per value.

```
list = [['a','b'],['c','a'],['c','b']]
```

output:

```
unique_value = [[1,2],[3,1],[3,2]]
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what language you're using. Is that Python?

Answer (score 0):

I've mapped the string elements using the length of the dict here, maybe you can change it as per your requirement.
Code:

```py
def custom_map(arr):
    res = []
    for ele in arr:
        if ele not in cmap:
            cmap[ele]=len(cmap)+1
        res.append(cmap[ele])
    return res
cmap = {}
x = [['a','b'],['c','a'],['c','b']]
uq_val = list(map(custom_map,x))
print(uq_val)
```

Comment: @AliAlobaidi Welcome. Please mark the answer as correct if you got the solution

Comment: You can use `setdefault` to remove the `if` condition: `res.append(cmap.setdefault(ele, len(cmap)+1))`